# How to solve NameError while importing csv in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I having problem in importing csv files.I got error like this "NameError in Employee_attendances#index".

Model

```
class EmployeeAttendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :emp_id, :in_time, :out_time, :status



    def self.import(file)
            CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
            @employee_attendance  = EmployeeAttendance.find_by_emp_id_and_date(row['employee_id'],row['date'].to_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) || EmployeeAttendance.new
            @employee_attendance.emp_id                = row['emp_id']
            @employee_attendance.in_time               = row['in_time']
            @employee_attendance.out_time              = row['out_time']
            @employee_attendance.status                = row['status']
            @employee_attendance.date                  = row['date']
            @employee_attendance.save!
        end
    end

end
```

In controller

```
class EmployeeAttendancesController < ApplicationController

 def index
 end

 def new
 end

 def create
 end

 def import
   EmployeeAttendance.import(params[:file])
   redirect_to EmployeeAttendance_path, notice: "Sucessfully Created."
   end
end
```

In view (index.html.erb)

```
<% if flash[:notice].present? %>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <%= flash[:notice] %>
    </div>
<% end %>
<div>
    <h2>Employee Attendance</h2>
</div>
<%= form_tag import_employee_attendance_index_path, multipart: true do %>
<%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

It showing error like "undefined local variable or method `import_employee_attendance_index_path' for #<#:0xb30a8c88>"

Comment: It appears that you do not have the route defined or you misspelled it.  Please check result of `rake routes`.

Comment: please provide `routes.rb` code

Comment: can you please share your routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your routes file :

```
resources :employee_attendances do
  collection do
    post 'import'
  end
end
```

or this :

```
resources :employee_attendances do
  post 'import', on: :collection
end
```

and this to view:

```
<%= form_tag import_employee_attendances_path, multipart: true do %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not added `routes` for the method `import`, add following in your `routes.rb`

```
resources :employee_attendances  do 
  post 'import' 
end
```

restart your server and then following line

```
<%= form_tag import_employee_attendance_path, multipart: true do %>
```

Comment: please provide `routes.rb` code, or o/p of the `rake routes | grep 'import'`

Comment: I have given resources :employee_attendances in routes.rb file

Comment: you have to add `routes` for the method `import`, check my edited answer it should work for you

Comment: Thanks for reminding the routes.rb file.I have changed that file.Now it's working fine